# Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"players\"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm just starting out with Mongoose and MongoDB. I've tried everything i could find here on stackoverflow, however, i'm lost as i do not know what the problem is.

I have the following 2 models, which reside in 2 different files:

```
var UserSchema = require('mongoose').model('User').schema;
var tournamentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    tournamentName: String,
    nrOfPlayers: String,
    players: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: UserSchema }],
    openForLeagues: {
        leagues: []
    },
    edition: String,
    description: String,
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    startHour: String,
    prize: Boolean,
    sponsors: String,
    ingameChatChannel: String,
    twitchStreamChannel: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tournament', tournamentSchema);

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local: {
        nickname: String,
        battlenetid: String,
        email: String,
        password: String,
        race: String,
        league: String,
        role: String,
        website: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Inside my routes.js file, i do the following:

```
app.post('/signup-tournament/:_id/:userId', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    var playerId = req.params.userId;
    var nickname = req.user.local.nickname;

    console.log(ObjectId.isValid(req.params.userId)); //true
    console.log(ObjectId.isValid(req.params._id)); //true
    if (ObjectId.isValid(playerId) && ObjectId.isValid(req.params._id)) {
        Tournament.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, {
            $pushAll: {
                players: {
                    values: [playerId, nickname]
                }
            }
        }, function(err, tournament) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            else
                res.redirect('/signup-tournament/' + req.params._id + req.params.userId);
        });
    }
});
```

When i do the post, i get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"players\"",
    "name": "CastError",
    "type": "ObjectId",
    "value": [{
        "values": ["53e340b3afb9657f0dbcf994", "cristidrincu"]
    }],
    "path": "players"
}
```

I do not understand why there is a cast error when the ids are validated using ObjectId.isValid()... I've spent 2 days trying to figure this on my own, so please help :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to perform `findByIdAndUpdate` operation which is against your `tournamentSchema`. The problem is in the following code:

```
Tournament.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, {
  $pushAll: {
    players: {
      values: [playerId, nickname]
    }
  }
})
```

`players` should contain `User` objects, so it should be either player's `_id` (hex `String` or `ObjectId`), or valid `User` object with `_id` field.

But you're trying to push invalid object `{ values: [playerId, nickname] }` instead.

Here is how this operation should look:

```
Tournament.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, {
  $pushAll: {
    players: [playerId]
  }
})
```

**N.B.** Not sure what does `nickname` mean in your example, but it doesn't look like a valid `ObjectId`, so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've removed the nickname, but the error is back: {"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"players\"","name":"CastError","type":"ObjectId","value":[{"values":["53e340b3afb9657f0dbcf994"]}],"path":"players"}

Comment: With your code: $pushAll: {
    players: [playerId]
  } i get the following error:{"name":"MongoError","errmsg":"exception: Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array","code":10141,"ok":0}

Comment: @user1895657 The only explanation for this error is that you already have `Tournament` object in MongoDB, which is against your mongoose `tournamentSchema`, so `findByIdAndUpdate` fails.

Comment: You, sir, deserve a medal. That was the problem, i was having a Tournament object in MongoDB which caused this problem. Removed it and now everything works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks for the explanation :). Btw, don't know why they didn't vote this answer ><